# Sum of all numbers in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm currently learning C# and running into some trouble with multi dimension array.

I can't seem to figure out how to find the sum of all the elements in the array. E.g

```
int[,] array = { { 52, 76, 65 }, { 98, 87, 93 }, { 43, 77, 62 }, { 72, 73, 74 } };
```

So the sum should be:

> 52 + 76 + 65 + 98 + ...

I have tried to use the for loop but that just give me the sum of each array in dimension 1. E.g

```
private int[,] array = { { 52, 76, 33}, { 98, 87, 93 }, { 43, 77, 62 }, { 72, 73, 74 } };
public void ArraySum()
{      
    double sum;        
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        sum = 0;                   
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)    
            sum += array[i, j];            

        Console.WriteLine("The sums are for the array  {0} is {1}: ", i, sum);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move the line `sum = 0;` out of the first loop:

```
private int[,] array = { { 52, 76, 33}, { 98, 87, 93 }, { 43, 77, 62 }, { 72, 73, 74 } };
public void ArraySum()
{      
    int sum = 0;        
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)    
            sum += array[i, j];            
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The sum for the whole array is {0}: ", sum);
}
```

In your code the `sum` is reset to `0` for each sub-array.

**Edit**
Since the array contains `int` values, consider to declare the `sum` variable as `int` instead of `double`.

Comment: Geez didn't realize it was that easy. Spend an hour yesterday trying to figure it out. Love this site already.

Comment: @Dchau Glad you like us. I highly suggest learn about breakpoints and stepping through the code  =)

Answer (score 5):

The other answer pointed out what's wrong with your code. Here's a short alternative to your loops using LINQ:

```
int[,] array = { { 52, 76, 65 }, { 98, 87, 93 }, { 43, 77, 62 }, { 72, 73, 74 } };
int sum = array.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

The `Cast` is used to convert the multidimensional array to an `IEnumerable<int>` which then allows you to use the `Sum` extension method.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're just learning and playing around anyway, you could use a `List<int<int>>` to store your values instead of a 2-dimensional array, like this:

```
var array = new List<List<int>>
             {
                 new List<int> {52, 76, 65},
                 new List<int> {98, 87, 93},
                 new List<int> {43, 77, 62},
                 new List<int> {72, 73, 74}
             };
```

Then you could easily use LINQ to get your sum:

```
var sum = array.SelectMany(x => x).Sum();
```

If you haven't heard of it yet, you can [learn more about LINQ here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Basically, `SelectMany()` flattens your multiple lists into one list, and then `Sum()` just adds them all up.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the sum of the entire array, then

```
private static int[,] array = { { 52, 76, 33}, { 98, 87, 93 }, { 43, 77, 62 }, { 72, 73, 74 } };

public static void Main()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            sum += array[i, j];
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The sum for the array is {0}: ", sum);
}
```